# Which function to be used for URL assertion in Dusk?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk

```
public function testPagination()
{
    $this->browse(function($first)
    {
        $first->loginAs(\App\User::find(1))
              ->visit('http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/user');
    });
    $this->browse(function(Browser $browser)
    {
        $browser->visit('http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=1')
                ->clickLink('2')
                ->assertUrlIs('http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=2');
    });
}
```

Error
1) Tests\Browser\MessageTest::testPagination
Actual URL [http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=2] does not equal expected URL [http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=2].
Failed asserting that 'http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog' matches PCRE pattern "/^http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog\?page\=2$/u".

Both URL seems to be the same for me. I am trying to click "2" resulting from pagination. The screenshot shows that click has been successfully done. 
When i run command php artisan dusk. Error i have given pops up and testing fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assertUrlIs Asserts that the current URL (**without the query string**) matches the given string:

```
$browser->assertUrlIs($url);
```

There is no method provided by Laravel Dusk to match the URL with the query string.

You can do something like this

```
$this->assertEquals($browser->driver->getCurrentURL() , 'your-url');
```

Comment: it is showing as assertEquals() is an undefined method.

Comment: assertEquals is a method from phpunit, should work on the class instance $this->assertEquals , $browser->assertEquals won't work since it's not an dusk method

Comment: 1) Tests\Browser\MessageTest::testPagination
Actual path [/mailLog] does not equal expected path [http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=2].
Failed asserting that '/mailLog' matches PCRE pattern "/^http\:\/\/mettledlp\.in\.linuxense\.com\/mailLog\?page\=2$/u".   still eror

Comment: Try this  $browser->visit('http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=1')
                ->clickLink('2'); $this->assertEquals($browser->driver->getCurrentURL() , 'http://mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=2');

Answer (score 0):

Assert that the given query string parameter is present and has a given value:

```
$browser->assertQueryStringHas($name, $value);
```

so you can test url with query string like this:

```
$browser->visit('mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog?page=1')
->clickLink('2')
->assertUrlIs('mettledlp.in.linuxense.com/mailLog')
->assertQueryStringHas('page','2');
```

Comment: Please add some details to your answer such that others can learn from it